# How does the "successive passes in opposite direction" improvement work for bubble sort?

Tags: sorting, bubble-sort

According to *Data Structures Using C* by Tenenbaum, one of the improvements of bubble sort is to have successive passes go in opposite direction so that the small elements move quickly to the front which will reduce the required number of passes [pg 336].
I worked out two examples, one which supports this statement and other which is against this one.

```
Supports: 25 48 37 12 57 86 33 92
iterations using usual Bubble sort :
    25 48 37 12 57 86 33 92
    25 37 12 48 57 33 86 92
    25 12 37 48 33 57 86 92
    12 25 37 33 48 57 86 92
    12 25 33 37 48 57 86 92

iterations using improvement:
    25 48 37 12 57 86 33 92
    25 37 12 48 57 33 86 92
    12 25 37 33 48 57 86 92
    12 25 33 37 48 57 86 92

against: 3 4 1 2 5
iterations using usual Bubble sort:
    3 4 1 2 5
    3 1 2 4 5
    1 2 3 4 5

iterations using improvement:
    3 4 1 2 5
    3 1 2 4 5
    1 3 2 4 5
    1 2 3 4 5
```

So is the statement incorrect that this improvement will always help? Or I am doing something wrong here ?

Answer (score 0):

The example you gave above shows that this algorithm isn't a strict improvement over a standard bubble sort.

The advantage of this approach (sometimes called "cocktail sort," by the way) is that in cases where there are a lot of small elements at the end of the array, it rapidly pulls them to the front compared against normal bubble sort. For example, consider this array:

```
2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 ... 10,000,000 1
```

With a normal bubble sort, it would take 9,999,999 passes over this array to sort it because the element 1, which is way out of place, only gets swapped one step forward on each iteration. On the other hand, with a cocktail sort, this would take just two passes - one initial pass and then a reverse pass.

While the above example is definitely contrived, in a randomly-shuffled array, there are likely going to be some smaller elements toward the end of the array and the number of passes of bubblesort is going to have to be large to move them back. Going in both directions helps speed this up.

That said, bubblesort is a pretty poor choice of a sorting algorithm, so hopefully this is just a theoretical discussion. :-)